# Stop ASP.Net from recycling app pool due to "changes to the bin"

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis-7, web-config

Greetings,
 I have a large .Net web app which runs on a farm of blades with the code base on a NAS. Every once in a while slight fluctuations in the response time of the nas cause .NET to think that something in the bin has changed and kick off a recycle of the app pool. No change has actually occurred. Is there a way to disable .Net's monitoring of changes to the bin?

Comment: What makes you think this is the cause if nothing in /bin has changed?

Comment: Heh, heh, I like the way that question starts: "Stop ASP.Net."

Comment: Keltex, because we has logging on the app pool and it says that's the reason for the restart.

Comment: "slight fluctuations in the response time of the nas cause .NET", prove it please. Sounds unlikely. "It says that's the reason"; what's "that" here? There *are* issues with IIS using non-local hard drives as application folders.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about this question. We ended up getting some kind of fix for the nas from IBM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will put an end to it. Now you must do `iisreset` to recycle your app pool.

```vb
'This is supposed to turn off the monitoring for directory deletes
'See https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/Workaround.aspx?FeedbackID=240686
'This incurs the penalty of an IISRESET or manually restarting the containing AppPool after every upgrade.
Dim pi As PropertyInfo
Dim o As Object
Dim m As MethodInfo
pi = GetType(System.Web.HttpRuntime).GetProperty("FileChangesMonitor", BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Static)
o = pi.GetValue(Nothing, Nothing)
m = o.GetType().GetMethod("Stop", BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
m.Invoke(o, New Object() {})
```

Comment: Having attempted to use this again this much more recently, we don't think it works in .NET 4 websites. Oh well. It works just fine in .NET 2 and 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

There also seems to be a hot fix that appears to be able to disable the "feature" with a Registry entry:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/911272

Not entirely sure that this works on the bin or not.

Answer (score -2):

The simple answer is, you cannot.  If IIS detects a change in one of the binaries, it must reload in order to ensure that it is using the correct binaries.

The real questions are:
 a) Is IIS truly detecting a change, or is it due to the "fluctuation" causing the OS to think the files aren't there momemtarily?
 b) If the "fluctuations" are the root of the issue, what is causing them?  How can that be addressed?

Comment: Well, that's the big question, and one we are looking into as well. I was just hoping there would be a stopgap solution because the nas issue may be bigger.